# Task using lambda gives a compile-time error

Tags: c#, lambda

I've searched here on StackOverflow and several other places, but never found an exact answer to this. In WPF application, I'm trying to implement a task using lambda multi-line code block, and I get a "not all code paths return a value". How do I return a `Func<string>` from this?

```
private async void btnLongOperation_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lblResult.Content = "Commencing long-running operation...";
        var task = Task.Run<string>(() => 
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            lblResult.Content = "Finishing long-running operation...";
        });


        lblResult.Content = await task;
    }

Error   1   Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'System.Func<string>'
```

Comment: The lambda should have a `return` statement in it, it doesn't have anything to do with multi-line lambdas. Don't set the content there, return the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Task.Run<string>` gives an input of type `Func<string>`. It means it has no input (`()`) and must return an string. So this may help:

```
 var task = Task.Run<string>(() => 
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        //Here
        return "Finishing long-running operation...";
    });
```

Comment: Note to OP - the lblResult.Content was removed because the line `lblResult.Content = await task;` already performs this logic when the task completes.

Comment: Gosh! I was so blind! Thank you guys. Indeed there are days when you just hitting the wall...